# Problem Requiring Little Picard's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

While preparing for an exam I got stuck on the following question.

Let $f$ and $g$ be entire functions such that $f(0) = g(0)$ and let $p$ and $q$ be polynomials such that the following equality holds: $e^{f(z)}+p(z) = e^{g(z)}+q(z)$. Prove, using the Picard's Little Theorem, that $f = g$ and $p=q$.

I know the objective is to construct a function which omits two values, yet I don't have any solid idea how to begin. Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Write the equation as 
$$ e^{f(z)} - e^{g(z)} = r(z)$$ 
where $r(z) = q(z) - p(z)$ is a polynomial.  Whenever $f(z) - g(z)$ is a multiple of $2 \pi i$, $r(z) = 0$.  Now how many such $z$'s will there be?

Comment: Precisely the hint I needed. Thank you very much :)